# Adjusting total number of slides shown in beamer

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

Using Beamer how can someone change the number shown as the total number of pages so that the slides will show differing numbers of total slides?

E.g.

slide 1 has 1/4 in the footer

slide 5 has 5/23 in the footer

Comment: I think you have to more specific where and why you want to change the total number (like count for each section, or just change a page manually with any number)